# Quartz update next fire time in db

Tags: sql-update, quartz-scheduler, manual

Instead of deploying the entire application everytime. In my local testing is there a way to update the database table directly the quartz next fire time in db.
Will it pick it up without restarting the server?
And how to update the time. what functions it uses to generate the time

QRTZ_TRIGGERS is the table it is referring to

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can update the value in table **[QRTZ_TRIGGERS]**. It is column **[NEXT_FIRE_TIME]** and you have to provide value in ticks.
Also, Scheduler restart is required in order to pickup updated value.

You can use following example to generate ticks based on datetime value: [link](https://lazarus987.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/how-to-convert-tick-to-datetime-sql/)